# LightGbm: how to use eval_sample_weight

Tags: lightgbm

I am working on a binary classification problem in LightGbm (Scikit-learn API), and have a problem understanding how to include sample weights. My code currently looks like this

```
classifier = LGBMClassifier(n_estimators=100, learning_rate = 0.1, num_leaves = 15)    
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train, sample_weight = w_train, eval_set = (X_val, y_val))
```

Here `w_train` is a numpy array with the same dimension as y_train. But I need LightGbm to also use sample_weights on the validation set, so I set `eval_sample_weight` in the `fit` function. I expected this to also be an array `w_val` (with the same dimension as `y_val`), but I see from the documentation that this is a list of arrays. I can not find any examples using this, so I struggle to understand why. To my understanding, this should just be a weight for each element in the validation set. A list of arrays: would this mean multiple weights for each sample? Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Figured this out myself. LightGbm accepts a list of validation sets. So, it also of course accepts a list of weights. One set of weights for each validation set.

Comment: Do you know if the weights need to follow any constraints or they can be any +ve number as long as their ratio reflects what we need? (My guessing only the ratio matters since the loss is additive.)

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem here and can you share the code on how you solve it? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

[Petter T](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1999917/petter-t) is right, it should be a list of arrays, each array corresponding to each `eval_set`.
So the code should look like following:

```
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train, sample_weight = w_train, eval_set = (X_val, y_val), eval_sample_weight = [w_val])
```

where, as described before, `w_val` shape is equal to shape of `y_val`.

Comment: And in the cross-validation scenario, `eval_sample_weight` needs to be passed the validation part of each fold's data.

Comment: BTW, XGBoost equivalent of `eval_sample_weight` is called `sample_weight_eval_set`.

Comment: Thanks for this, why are there brackets on eval_sample_weight? andn ot sample_weight? what I don't get is that I have the code as you have it and it runs, but if I remove the bracket it fails. doesn't make sense to me.